# Enviar informação via post com Ajax e retornar valores separados

Tags: php, ajax

Aqui tenho um código para abrir modal enviando o idcolaborador para buscar no arquivo cadastro.php e retornar nas variáveis.
Exemplo: data.data6, data.Colaborador6, data.Observacao6...

Dúvida: Queria saber como faço no php para atribuir as variáveis fazendo uma consulta no BD de uma tabela e retornando os dados para a pagina com as variáveis.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data6', function(){  
       var idcolaborador = $(this).attr("Id");  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"cadastro.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{idcolaborador:idcolaborador},  
            dataType:"json",  
            success:function(data){ 

                 $('#data6').val(data.data6);
                 $('#Colaborador6').val(data.Colaborador6); 
                 $('#Observacao6').val(data.Observacao6);
                 $('#Estado1').prop("checked", data.Estado);
                 $('#Conclusao').val(data.Conclusao);
                 $('#idcolaborador').val(data.Id6);
                 $('#insert6').val("Gravar");                    
                 $('#exampleModal6').modal('show');              
            }  
       });  
  });
```

```html
<?php
$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
$Query = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM colaboradores WHERE id='".$dados['idcolaborador']."'")or die(mysql_error()); ?>
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){ 
$data6 = $row['data6'];
$Colaborador6 = $row['Colaborador6'];
$Conclusao= $row['Conclusao'];
$Id6= $row['Id6'];} ?>
```

Comment: `dataType:"json"`, no AJAX você está esperando um JSON, então precisa fazer o PHP responder com um JSON. Leia sobre a função `json_encode` do PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz essa alteração do PHP, mas mesmo assim não está trazendo o valor na pagina com o exemplo do JS que mencionei acima. O que estou precisando é que os valores venham separados para usar em diferentes id na página.

```html
<?php
$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
$Query = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM colaboradores WHERE id='".$dados['idcolaborador']."'")or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){ 
  $resultado_dados = array(
    'data6' => $row['data6'],
    'Colaborador6' => $row['Colaborador6'],
    'Observacao6' => $row['Observacao6'],
  );
}

echo(json_encode($resultado_dados));

?>
```